# X Unit test not compatible with .net core 2.2

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

I have web application with `.net core 2.2`.

I want to test my web application with `XUnit` or `MSUnit` but o have problem with it.

The version of the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package in `XUnit` project is 2.1.0 and version of the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` in api project is 2.2.

I search many hours and do everything that i see but dosent work.
what should i do ?

Comment: Update your App package in `XUnit project` to `2.2`. It works fine for me :  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />`

Answer (score 2):

Just Add

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>`

To your test project, rebuild and it shall be fine.

Here's a sample of my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

...

</Project>
```

you can check the issue from [this](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1858)

Answer (score 1):

As you cans see on [this](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1835) link, the same issue was opened on Github and seems like no solution is delivered by XUnit. I am using Nunit with my .NET Core v2.2 project and it works fine. To have look at the library you can check [this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit) page out. The syntax is very similar to XUnit and I guess it won't take you so long to update your tests. So, I would suggest you to migrate NUnit.

Comment: NUnit has one important difference, XUnit instantiate new instance of test class for every test method where NUnit instantiate only one instance of test class for all tests in it.